WhatsApp Flows: How to Bold Specific Words in Messages
I'm new to WhatsApp Flows and struggling to find the option to bold part of my text. The documentation includes an image showing bold formatting (screenshot below), but I don't see that feature available. Could this be a future update, or am I missing something? I've also considered the possibility of multiple items in a row, but the current WhatsApp Flows API has one type of layout, SingleColumnLayout, which makes that unlikely.


Currently it is not possible to bold only part of the text.
